# unsaved comment edits are lost when showing new comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing, comments

When I do the following...

- post a comment
- start editing the comment I recently posted
- see that newer comments have been posted
- click the link to show the newer comments

...my editing of my [less than 5 minutes] old comment is cancelled, and I lose the changes I haven't posted.

Comments are limited in both length and importance, so this is not as bad as other possible bugs that could cause loss of unsaved work, but it is annoying and reduces productivity.

Furthermore, it seems unlikely that this behavior is by design, since I can show new comments when *writing a new comment of my own* and I don't lose my progress composing the new comment.

Comment: nice catch, I usually do an instinctive "Copy" then hit the show new comments, and paste it back if it is wiped out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely agreed that this isn't quite the expected user interface behavior. It [will behave correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130386/clicking-show-comment-while-editing-a-comment-cancels-the-edit-to-the-comment/164906#164906) after the next build of the site.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, cool! Thanks for all your work attending to the SE network and making it better. (Also, Unicornify is kinda neat. Heh.)